# What would "I forgot my keys" mean in this situation?

Tags: meaning, grammar, present-perfect, comparisons, past-vs-present

If you were at the door and found out that you had forgotten your keys you might say: "I have forgotten my keys" ..

but what would it mean if you said **I forgot my keys** instead?

Comment: I think most people would be far more likely to say "I forgot my keys" if they forgot their keys. The act of forgetting took place in the recent/immediate past so there is no need for the present participle.

Comment: No need for two extra syllables to say something obvious. Most of the time speakers have a choice between perfect and past, unless there's some aspect they want to emphasize.

Comment: Are they talking with formal English grammar or it is the same?

Comment: @user37421 I’m betting you that are taking your cues from some English-as-a-second-language instruction book that presents so oversimplified a version of reality as to have no bearing on the same. If so, throw it out because it is full of lies.

Comment: @PaulRichter: Not in my part of the English-speaking world. "I've forgotten my keys" sounds much more normal to me.

Comment: @tchrist Why do you think that using English in this way would be simpler than using it with both ways? I think these second language books then are in fact more complicated!

Comment: @ColinFine Well either might be used but they would mean different things. If one's mind was not focused upon any particular moment of forgetting, then *I have forgotten my keys* would be fine. However if, one was reflecting back on the time one was actually gathering one's possessions together, one might say *After all that, I forgot my keys*.

Comment: Yes, @WS2, in a different situation from the one the OP posited, one might indeed say something different.

Comment: @ColinFine As with a lot of English, specially the choice between perfect and past simple, it can depend on what you were thinking when you said it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about "the recent past," it would mean you were speaking American English and not British English. For a situation (or, in a context) such as this, BrE prefers the present perfect and deprecates the simple past, while AmE can go either way  but the simple past is probably most natural.

See **Use of the Present Perfect** in [Differences Between American and British English](http://esl.about.com/od/toeflieltscambridge/a/dif_ambrit.htm). I suppose it's only fortuitous that they use as an example a sentence about losing one's keys.

Another situation, from *The English Verb* by Palmer is the situation where a family is (American English) or are (British English) preparing to have dinner, and the child reports whether his hands are clean.

In British English the child will report:

> Yes, I've just washed them.

while

in a American English, the response is more likely to be, or at least just as likely,

> I just washed them.

This blog post on [the present perfect](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/08/present-perfect.html?m=1) on *separated by a common language* is well written, despite the author being a linguist. :)  It's one I highly recommend. It goes into the nuances of what the present perfect expresses that the simple past does not, usually.

Comment: You mean in the last sentence "... that the simple past does not"??

Comment: It's not so obvious that the British use of the perfect here is not a past tense.  There is an analysis which derives a perfect "have" from a past tense, coming from examples like "I believe he eats" ==> "I believe him to eat", "I believe he ate" ==> "I believe him to have eaten".